# Why is the inverse of a unimodularity matrix integral?

Tags: linear-algebra

We were not taught about unimodular matrices in my linear algebra class, so I do not have any formal coverage of it. From Wikipedia, a unimodular matrix $U$ is a matrix over the ring of integers, with determinant $1,-1$. By definition, it is obvious why $U$ has an inverse. Also by definition, it is obvious that $U$ can only have an inverse with integer entries if the determinant of $U$ is $1$ or $-1$. It is not obvious why unimodular matrices must have integral inverse though.

**Edit:** Marktmeister gave the answer in the comment. The formula of the inverse of a matrix is $$\frac{1}{det(U)} C^T$$, where $C$ is the co-factor matrix. Obviously, the entries of the cofactor matrix is built using only ring operations of $\mathbb{Z}$, and thus must be in $\mathbb{Z}$ as well.

Comment: A formula for the inverse is given by $U^{-1} = 1/\det(U) \cdot \mathrm{adj}(U)$, where $\mathrm{adj}$ denotes the adjugate matrix. Since this adjugate is integral by definition, it follows that $U^{-1}$ is integral, too.

Comment: @Marktmeister I had a brain fart. Yes, it is now obvious, thank you!